# Не работает бекап БД

Tags: php, mysql

Всем добрый день. Написал скрипт бекапа баз данных но он почему то не работает. Кто может помочь разобраться ?

```
// Тут подключение к базе
$user_mysql = 'admin';
$pass_mysql = '12345';

$tmp_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/damp/';
#функция выводит в массив список баз данных
function get_database_tables()
{
    $ret = array();
    $r = mysql_query('SHOW DATABASES');
    if (mysql_num_rows($r)>0)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_NUM))
        {
            $ret[] = $row[0];
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

$h=array();#В этом массиве бум хранить список бд
$h=get_database_tables();#Заполняем его именами баз данных
$vsego=count($h);#Узнаем, сколько именно баз в массиве

$exс=array('information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema', 'phpmyadmin');

for ($x=0; $x < $vsego; $x++){
    $bd=$h[$x];
    #И сделаем их дамп
    if(!in_array($bd, $exс)){
        exec('mysqldump -u '.$user_mysql.' -p'.$pass_mysql.' --opt '.$bd.' > ' . $tmp_path . $bd . '.sql');
    }
}
```

Скрипт работает но создает пустые файлы с именами баз данных.

Comment: Так вы выведите содержимое exec на экран и выполните команды ручками. Увидите что за ошибка у вас

UPD (комменты закончились): у вас есть команда `mysqldump -u admin -p12345 --opt 111 > Z:/home/test.ru/www/uploads/damp/111.sql`. Вот ее надо вставить в командную строку и запустить (см. [как открыть](http://softlakecity.ru/os/windows/windows7/kak-vyizvat-komandnuyu-stroku-v-windows-7)). Причем запускать надо из той же папки, из которой вы запускали скрипт. Если скрипт запускали по HTTP, то попробуйте запустить из папки, которая ваш скрипт содержит

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить. Но как вывести на экран ?

Comment: Как-то так:

    $command = 'mysqldump -u '.$user_mysql.' -p'.$pass_mysql.' --opt '.$bd.' > ' . $tmp_path . $bd . '.sql';
    // exec($command);
    echo "{$command}\n";

Comment: Ну а чем мне это поможет вот один из ответов mysqldump -u admin -p12345 --opt 111 > Z:/home/test.ru/www/uploads/damp/111.sql все правильно вроде как

Comment: Ошибки с подключением к БД нет. Ведь функция get_database_tables обращается к базе данных и создает массив БД который в последствии и перебирается. А раз функция отрабатывает значит подключение к бд верное.

Comment: @alexsis20102, ну вот зачем вы все усложняете? Я же написал - выполнить ручками команды, которые вы генерируете, и проверить результат. Вы это сделали? Команды выполнили все так, как ожидалось?

Остальное это догадки, т.к. у вас не показано как вы подключаетесь, поэтому я не могу утверждать что логин/пароль верные. Да это и не важно, главное, чтобы вы проверили работу команд.

Если они не работают при ручном вызове, то в скрипте они работать так же не будут.

Comment: @BOPOH 

    exec('mysqldump -u '.$user_mysql.' -p'.$pass_mysql.' --opt '.$bd.' > ' . $tmp_path . $bd . '.sql');

![](http://i.imgur.com/5SkUNRj.jpg)

    $commandTemplate = 'mysqldump -u%s -p%s --opt %s > %s';
    $outputFile = $tmpDir . $databaseName . '.sql';
    $command = sprintf($commandTemplate, $user, $password, $databaseName, $outputFile);
    exec($command);

![](http://i.imgur.com/CYqwfH1.jpg)

Comment: @alexsis20102 Я Вам привёл [shell-скрипт](http://hashcode.ru/questions/392722#392758), который создаёт дампы и складывает их в архив. Если необходимо все эти операции выполнить на PHP, возьмите всё необходимое из него и выполните с помощью `exec`.

И ещё, перестаньте стучаться к СУБД через процедуры (`mysql_query`, `mysql_num_rows`, ...). Прочитайте, что написано [в красной рамке на оф.сайте](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) и вдогонку ["Почему стоит пользоваться PDO"](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/).

Comment: @Etki, это единственное, что вы увидели? И при чем здесь я? Я потратил все комменты на то, чтобы просто попросить выполнить команду, а на форматирование и последующее объяснение ушел бы еще не один коммент. При этом какое отношение это имело бы к решению задачи? Результат был бы тем же.

@alexsis20102, вы пытались выполнить команду ручками? У вас все получилось? Если нет, то причину надо в этом искать, а не в коде. И зачем вам `--opt`? Он по дефолту включен, уберите его.

У меня комменты закончились, а для ответа я так и не получил от вас ничего конкретного, писать могу только удаляя старое

Comment: @BOPOH, а это не вам, простите, это автору

Comment: Спасибо за коменты буду пробовать.